# Program gives program.exe has stopped working about 4 second after starting it

Tags: c++, c++11, process

I am new to coding and I am trying to create a retro style game.
The idea is to have each square in the game be part of a string. Here is the code I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int a,b=0;
   char s[9][77]={};

   while (true) {
     s[a][b]={'_'};
     b+=1;
     if (b>77){
        a+=1;
        b=0;
     }
     if (a>9){
        a=0;
        b=0;
        break;
     }
   }
   s[0][0]={'H'};

   cout << "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
   cout << "@" <<s[0][0]<<s[0][1];

   return 0;
}
```

When I run it after about 4 second it gives me:

> program.exe has stopped working.

If it helps I get the following when the error:

> msg is closed(in cmd ):process returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005)

and i get the following when compiling;

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

ps:the snippet of coding is just for testing that I don’t get errors.

Comment: omg, can't you just debug it?

Comment: Why the brackets for assigning a character?

Comment: Smiley face on line 11.

Comment: I'd recommend replacing your `while` loop by nested `for` loops, `std::fill_n` or a combination of those two. That will make the structure of your program a lot cleaner.

Comment: 1. a not initialized, 2. a>77 - you are actually writing into s[a][77]={'_'}; which would work for all but last iteration. for last itration you are writing beyond the array memory

Comment: 3. s[9][xx] when accesssed is going beyond the allocated. this is happening when a ebcomes 9

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, now I can't unsee it -_- </offtopic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
int a,b=0;
```

Here you declare two variables, but you only initialize *one* of them. This means that the value of `a` is undefined, and using it in e.g. `s[a][b]` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

```
 int a, b=0; // a is not initialized
```

Below while loop will access

```
while (true) {
 s[a][b] = {'_'};  // b will be 78, access s[a][78] out of bounds
 b+=1;
 if (b>77){
 //...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (b>77){
```

77 is already an illegal index; the test needs to use `>=`. Same for the one for `a` below.

And also the problem that Joachim found.

Comment: same issue with a>9 s[9][] is beyond allocated limit